# Setting up neo4j community edition on a server

Tags: neo4j, server

I am trying to use a server to access an app I made that harnesses neo4j. The issue is, if I run neo4j community edition on the server. I don't know what url to point the app to, to find the database.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

The community edition does run like any other server program on a a server.

To connect through, one usually uses the Bolt protocol.

You need a [Driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/) for your language of choice.

We have official drivers for C#, Java, JavaScript, Python and Go.

On the server, open up the default port for Bolt, 7687.

The URL for your driver is then `bolt://your-host.something:7687`

Comment: Thanks Michael,
Does the driver get installed on the server? i am not entirely sure how 'npm' works

Comment: Do i need to be using Node js for this?